# Como colocar múltiplos ícones de acordo com o "mime-type" na mesma extensão

Tags: linux, icons, mime-type

A idéia é bem simples:

Tenho um **arquivo de texto**:  `texto.prisma`

> $ file -i texto.prisma
>
> texto.prisma: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Tenho outro **arquivo compilado**: `compilado.prisma`

> $ file -i compilado.prisma
>
> compilado.prisma: application/octet-stream; charset=binary

**Quero um ícone para cada tipo de arquivo da mesma extensão.**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Vamos aos fatos:

não vou ficar explicando sobre mime-types aqui.

Quem quiser fazer isso siga essa receita:

A distro em questão é linux Ubuntu 16.04 64bits

1. Crie um arquivo de ícone chamado `application-prisma.svg` 256x256px e coloque em `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes` então o caminho completo vai ser: **`/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes/application-prisma.svg`**
2. Crie outro ícone application-**x**-prisma.svg e coloque no mesmo local então o caminho vai ficar: **`/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes/application-x-prisma.svg`**
3. crie um arquivo chamado `prisma.xml` e coloque em `/usr/share/mime/packages` então o caminho completo vai ficar: **`/usr/share/mime/packages/prisma.xml`**
4. cole o seguinte código no arquivo prisma.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="application/x-prisma">
        <sub-class-of type="application/octet-stream"/>
        <comment>Prisma compilado</comment>
        <glob pattern="*.prisma"/>
        <glob pattern="*.pris"/>
    </mime-type>
    <mime-type type="application/prisma">
        <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
        <comment>Prisma texto</comment>
        <glob pattern="*.prisma"/>
        <glob pattern="*.pris"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

5. execute os seguintes comandos:

> **$ sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime && sudo gtk-update-icon-cache**

6. E VUALÁ

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]